# Reuse mocks, or avoid duplicated mocks in unit and integration (end to end) tests in angular

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, testing, integration-testing

Is there a way to reuse mocks for unit and integration (end to end, e2e) tests in angular applications? I do not want to edit, copy or maintain two versions of the mocked data!

**Edit:** I am interested on end to end tests made with protractor, since it is suggested for future projects in the angular doc

Comment: What are you using for integration testing? Angular scenario or Protractor? AFAIK what you want to do is very difficult with Protractor.

Comment: Protractor, i edited the question

Comment: I’m wondering if you have considered having an Angular service/factory that returns the mock data? I mean having it as an Angular module would let you use in different tests, wouldn’t it? 8-)

Comment: So after i wrote this question i wrote my own utility script https://github.com/danse/mockatenate. Eventually i stopped maintaining integration tests because protractor was too fragile at that time and maintaining those tests too expensive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write tests for classes with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709906/how-to-write-tests-for-classes-with-inheritance)